# How to use system services like telephony manager and location manager services in a static method?

Tags: android

```
ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) SystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
SensorManager sm = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService
```

(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

Comment: What the problem are u facing now?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it as follows:

```
public class AccessData{
    public static void doSomething(final Context context){
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        // Use TelephonyManager object.
    }
}
```

You can access this method from Activity as follows:

```
AccessData.doSomething(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass your context as a parameter:

```
public static void foo(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    SensorManager sm = (SensorManager) context.getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
}
```

And use it like

```
foo(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

in Xamarin.Android (not sure for native Android) you can access the context from anywhere like this: Application.Context

With this way you don't need to pass it as a parameter.